# Custom hotkey in Launchy

Tags: ubuntu, hotkeys, launchy

I would like to use **Insert** (without modifiers) as the hotkey for Launchy in Ubuntu 10.04. How can I accomplish that?

*(A more general question is: how do I add whatever hotkey I want to Launchy?)*

*(A more philosophical question: why is the hotkey selection so limited?)*

The first question is the most important!